# Where can I find script library for new Photos app in Applescript editor

Tags: macos, applescript, apple-photos

I'm trying to automate something in the new Mac Photos app.

Initial research showed that the easy-to-use actions supplied of
for use with Mac Automator would not be sufficient for my needs, so I would like to try using the lower level Applescript language in Applescript editor.

But when I open the script editor and view libraries there is a listing for the old iPhotos app (greyed out) but not the new Photos app.

[image]

I've googled it to death but keep getting results that point to this site: https://photosautomation.com/index.html

There's nothing wrong with this site but it supplies a utilities library layered on top of the basic Photos scripting suite.

Where can I find the library for Photos to add to Applescript editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This drove me nuts for hours, but it turns out to be almost trivially easy.
Just click the + button, and find the Photos.app in the Applications folder. Choose that and your done.

Comment: See also: File > Open Dictionary…